# Hide Xcode's toolbar in fullscreen mode

Tags: xcode, fullscreen

How can I hide Xcode's toolbar in fullscreen mode (`cmd` + `ctrl` + `f`)? 

I tried to hide it and then go into fullscreen but it appeared immediately. Also I tried to hide it using `right-click` -> `hide toolbar` but that did not work:

[image: disabled option to hide toolbar]

I just would like to have a clear screen with just code on it, w/o any useless toolbars.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://github.com/wczekalski/Distraction-Free-Xcode-plugin, it's a plugin in the making to provide a kind of Zen mode.

Comment: Thank you! It's a bit buggy and inconvenient but works somehow :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. On full screen the toolbar is always visible.

You can hide it only if you are out of full screen mode. If you want to do it with a key combination, you have to assign a shortcut on Preferences → Key Bindings (see the image below).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, are you 100% positive? Or is there any hope left for me? :D

Comment: Sorry, but I'm 100% sure, no way.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a custom Behaviour (`XCode → Preferences... → Behaviours`) with the action "Hide toolbar" and set a keyboard shortcut for it (press the `⌘` icon next to the name), triggering it will hide the toolbar even in fullscreen mode.

[image: Screenshot of XCode preferences window showing a custom Behaviour with the Hide toolbar action]